# Hide Label from prototype cell in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I am working on Prototype TableView Cell where I have two Label over cell and one button behind the cell. I want to hide the second label on Hide Button click. I have tried a lot but did not get any appropriate info, Here is my code for displaying the Labels in Cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableCell";
TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...

int row = [indexPath row];
cell.EnglishLable.text = _English[row];
cell.UrduLable.text = _Urdu[row];
return cell;
}
```

Everything is fine, I just need to hide 'UrduLabel' in my Hide IBAction method.

```
- (IBAction)Hide:(id)sender {



static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableCell";
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:IndexPath];
BOOL *hideLabel;
hideLabel = YES;
[self.tableView reloadData];
UILabel *subtitle = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
subtitle.hidden = hideLabel;
}
```

Whats wrong in my Button method?

Comment: Where the `-(IBAction)hide` in your code ? in the `viewcontroller` who is holding the `tableView` or inside the `TableViewCell` implementation ?

Comment: -(IBAction)hide is in my tableView class, not in TableViewCell class

Comment: What is gestureRecognizer in your - (IBAction)Hide method?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
- (IBAction)Hide:(id)sender {

CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

TableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.UrduLable.hidden = YES;
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:<any row animation you need>];

UILabel *subtitle = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
subtitle.hidden = hideLabel;

}
```

You just need to get the particular cell of which the button is clicked, hide the required label and reload the particular cell. And main thing is you need to get an instance of your prototype cell class, not of UITableViewCell

Answer (score 2):

**IN CASE ONE BUTTON IN THE VIEWCONTORLLER FOR ALL CELL**

Incase of single button toggling the visibility of the `UrduLabel`, declare the `-(IBAction)hide:(sender)id` in the `yourviewcontroller.m`. connect the `IBAction` of the button from nib/storyboard to the `-(IBAction)hide:(sender)id` method.

Then follow the following steps

1. declare a `BOOL` `property` variable or `ivar` inside the view controller. named `willShowUrdu`.
2. implement the `hide` as following:

   ```
   -(IBAction)hide:(id)sender
   {
       willShowUrdu = !(willShowUrdu);
       [yourTableView reloadData];
   }
   ```
3. inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

   ```
   TableViewCell *cell = //whatever the way you get the cell
   cell.UrduLabel.hidden = !willShowUrdu;
   ```

Thats how toggle the visibility of all `UrduLabel` under one `IBAction`.

**IN CASE OF EACH BUTTON IN EACH CELL**

There is a better way to de-centralize the control to each cell. Move the `-(IBAction)hide:(sender)id` method to the implementation in the `TableViewCell`'s implementation.

1. Add the IBAction from nib/storyboard to the moved `-(IBAction)hide:(sender)id` method.
2. Take a `IBOutlet` of the `UrduLabel`, as seen in above code, it's already taken.

Then the implementation of `-(IBAction)hide:(sender)id` would be following:

```
-(IBAction)hide:(sender)id
{
    //put your other logic here (if any)
    self.UrduLabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

Welcome to IOS, Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks Ratul Sir, its working but on Run Time the Urdu label is automatically hiding without pressing the Hide button :) 
Is there anything more to do?

Comment: Please don't call me sir, are you hiding the `UrduLabel` anywhere else ? give the label a background color  to distinguish that, are the `label` is actually hidden or no text available thats why the label is being hidden initially.

Comment: fine, I am assigining the UrduLable name as '_Urdu = @[@"Salam Habeebi"]' properly and in heightForRowAtIndexPath() return type: "UITableViewAutomaticDimension". I think there is mistake in return type because when I fixed it 0 then cell size became 0(zero) on Run time!

Comment: i want to hide UrduLabel bheind my Hide(IBAction)

Comment: yes, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is used for manually set the dynamic height of each `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: can't understand please, what do you mean by 'want to hide the UrduLabel behind the -(IBAction)hide' ?

Comment: there are 2 labels in a prototype cell, one is of English Language and second Label for Urdu language, I put a button on TableViewController and now want to hide the Urdu label behind that Button(Hide(IBAction)).

Comment: one single `UIButton` to toggle all the `UILabel` ?

Comment: Yes Exactly, 1 single button to hide the only 'UrduLabel'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103156/discussion-between-ratul-sharker-and-muhammad-zaheer).